# URL encode in Qt4

Tags: qt, qt4, urlencode

I'm trying to encode a URL while using Qt 4. It looks like in Qt 3, the method was `QUrl::encode`, but apparently `QUrl` was rewritten from Qt 3 to Qt 4. I looked in the documentation and didn't see any equivalent method. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also use [QUrl::toPercentEncoding](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding) to encode any QString without forming it to a URL.

Comment: Percent encoding isn't the same as url-encoding, what if "hello world" should become "hello%20world" or "hello+world"? `toPercentEncoding("hello world")` is a no-op.

Comment: I don't see any difference using the QUrl::toPercentEncoding method with Qt5. I tried to encode "hello world" and it is correctly encoded in "hello%20world"

Answer (score 1):

You want `QUrl::setEncodedUrl` and `QUrl::toEncoded`

Answer (score 0):

[Qt3 support members for QUrl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qurl-qt3.html#encode) points to *Stephen Chu*'s answer. Just added the link since it might be useful..